# Android Compose Boolean update only working in one direction

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a feature in my app that I currently only show when a saved preference value is true. Currently if said value is true the app shows the feature correctly on startup. Then if you set the value to false the app immediately removes said feature and stops showing it. The issue arises when you set said feature from false to true because the app doesn't show the feature to the users without somehow reloading the compose screen where it's supposed to be displayed (either through an app kill or navigating forward far enough and then back to said screen). Trying to understand what I might be doing that would lead to this behavior and if possible a way to make it so that the feature is responsive to both a positive and negative change in the preference value.

I tried setting the show / hide value as a MutableState variable that is only initially set by the preference value and then changes each time the preference gets updated however this entirely failed to change the behavior that I saw at all and instead simply stopped the 50% expected behavior of the preference updating from true to false causing the feature to disappear.

EDIT:
Code looks like this with '...' representing unrelated code snippets that I've hidden for clarity:

I've got a feature, in this case a priceSlider, that's contained inside a Column in the topBar composable of a Scaffold

```
@Composable
fun MyTopAppBar(
  sliderPosition: MutableState<ClosedFloatingPointRange<Float>>,
) {
  Column {
    ...
    if (getShouldShowPriceSlider(LocalContext.current)) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        PriceSlider(
            sliderPosition = sliderPosition,
        )
    }
  }
}
```

the user can open a Dialog that allows them to modify their preferences and change the value of the getShouldShowPriceSlider() function

```
fun ResultPreferencesDialog(
  onDismiss: () ->,
) {

  val context = LocalContext.current
  ...
  val shouldShowPriceSlider = remember {
      mutableStateOf(
        getShouldShowPriceSlider(context = context)
      )
  }
  ...
  AlertDialog(
    onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
    text = {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
             ...
             TextSwitch(
               mutableState = shouldShowPriceSlider,
               switchLabel = "Show Price Slider"
             )
             ...
          }
        }
    },
    confirmButton = {
        Button(onClick = {
            writeCommonAppPreferences(
                context = context,
                ...
                setShowPriceSlider = shouldShowPriceSlider.value,
                ...
            )
            onDismiss.invoke()
        }) {
            Text("Save")
        }
    },
)
```

and lastly the LocalPreferences file looks like this

```
private const val APP_PREFERENCES = "appPreferences"
private const val SHOW_PRICE_SLIDER_PREF = "showPriceSliderPref"

...
fun getShouldShowPriceSlider(context: Context): Boolean {
  return context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
      ?.getBoolean(SHOW_PRICE_SLIDER_PREF, true) ?: true
}
...

fun writeCommonAppPreferences(
  context: Context,
  ...
  setShowPriceSlider: Boolean,
  ...
) {
  val sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
  with(sharedPrefs.edit()) {
    ...
    putBoolean(SHOW_PRICE_SLIDER_PREF, setShowPriceSlider)
    ...
    apply()
  }
}
```

and as mentioned the weird thing is that if the Preference is updated from True (i.e. show the slider) to False it automatically disappears as the preference is updated. However if the Preference is updated from False to True it doesn't show up again automatically in the same way and I'm unsure as to why.

Comment: Show us the code.